# Getting dynamically added checkbox ID in Android

Tags: android

I'm adding a checkbox in my application dynamically, and I want to delete the records which are checked. But, I'm not getting the ID of the checkbox. How can I do this?

Code:

```
package com.my.StudentInfoManagement;


public class ListData extends Activity{

    DataHelper dh;
    TableLayout tb;
    CheckBox[] ch=new CheckBox[50];
    EditText ed;
    int a[]=new int[50];
    int k=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listdataxml);
        dh=new DataHelper(this);
        System.out.println("in list data");
        List<String> names= this.dh.selectAll();
        ed=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_id);
        tb=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
        int i,j=1;
        TextView name1 = null,id,dob,gender,branch,email,address,mobile;
        String name11,id1 = null,dob1,gender1,branch1,email1,address1,mobile1;
        TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);

        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);

        String c = null;
        String data[]=new String[50];

        int cnt=0;
        for(String name:names)
            {       
                if((!name.equals("-999")))
                {
                    data[cnt]=name;
                    cnt++;
                    System.out.println("........."+name);
                }
                else
                {
                    cnt=0;
                    name1=new TextView(this);
                    name1.setText(data[1]+" ");
                    id=new TextView(this);
                    id.setText(data[0]+" ");
                    System.out.println("ID is...."+data[0]);
                    dob=new TextView(this);
                    dob.setText(data[3]+" ");
                    gender=new TextView(this);
                    gender.setText(data[2]+" ");
                    branch=new TextView(this);
                    branch.setText(data[4]+" ");
                    mobile=new TextView(this);
                    mobile.setText(data[5]+" ");
                    email=new TextView(this);
                    email.setText(data[6]+" ");
                    address=new TextView(this);
                    address.setText(data[7]+" ");

                    tr=new TableRow(this);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    ch[k]=new CheckBox(this);
                    System.out.println("sysout");

                    i=Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                    ch[k].setId(i);

                    tr.addView(ch[k]);
                    a[k++]=i;

                    tr.addView(id);
                    tr.addView(name1);
                    tr.addView(dob);
                    tr.addView(gender);
                    tr.addView(branch);
                    tr.addView(mobile);
                    tr.addView(email);
                    tr.addView(address);
                tb.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(                         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    j++;
                    System.out.println("count"+j);  
                }
            }
    }

    public void delete(View v){
        System.out.println("In delete");
        int bb=k,id ;
         for (int i=0; i <k; i++) 
        {
             final int j = a[i];
             System.out.println("in for loop"+j);

                ch[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        System.out.println("Checked ID :: " + ch[j].getId());
                    }
                });
            }
        System.out.println("00000000000000000..."+id);
        dh.deleteData(id);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to getId from buttonView, did you try that?

Comment: im not getting you... on click of delete button this function is executing..

Comment: It seems based on your code, this code is being executed on your check box "check/Uncheck", not on button click.

Comment: With updated code, inside delete, you are checking for "Checkbox" event which may not likely happen. What you may need to do would be from "View v" look for "Check box" component and it's state.

Comment: i have resolved this problem successfully and my and is at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349461/getting-dynamically-added-checkbox-id-in-android

Answer (score 3):

strong textJust take a **global variable**

```
int chkId = 1001;
```

then at time of adding CheckBox **dynamically**, set its id as

```
ch.setId(++chkId);
```

then at time of deleting CheckBox, you can **get id of Checked** CheckBox simple by using

```
getId()
```

methhod

See Following Demo:

```
public class ChkBoxesActivity extends Activity {
    int chId = 1000;
    int chPos = -1;

    LinearLayout ll;
    String[] names = {"Tom", "Dick", "Keanu", "Harry", "Katrina", "Peter", "Julia", "Emma"};
    CheckBox[] ch;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        ch = new CheckBox[names.length];

        for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
            ch[i] = new CheckBox(this);
            ch[i].setId(chId++);
            System.out.println("CHID :: "+chId);
            System.out.println("I :: "+i);
            ch[i].setText(names[i]);
            ll.addView(ch[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            ch[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Checked ID :: " + ch[j].getId());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did that also.. i have set id to ch in previous function at the time of displaying data.each record have one checkbox.if i check one chechbox between that record..i want the checkbox id..

Comment: for(String name:names){  
    if((!name.equals("-999"))){
     sb.append(name+"         "); 
     }
    else
    {
     tr=new TableRow(this);
     tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     ch=new CheckBox(this);
     ch.setText(sb);
     tr.addView(ch);
     c=sb.charAt(0)+"";
     i=Integer.parseInt(c);
     ch.setId(i);
     a[k++]=i;
     sb=new StringBuilder();
     tb.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
   }

Comment: Do you want to delete CheckBox at the time of Checking it?

Comment: I have updated my answer and getting ID for all checkboxes, just check it, may be helpful for you.

Comment: its giving null ptr exceptn. at-  ch[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

Comment: Just do one thing, Just COPY my whole activity in your project and run it.

Comment: for(String name:names){  
 if((!name.equals("-999"))){
  data[cnt]=name;
  cnt++;
}else
{ cnt=0;
  name1=new TextView(this);
  name1.setText(data[1]);
  id=new TextView(this);
  id.setText(data[0]);
  tr=new TableRow(this);
  tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     ch[k]=new CheckBox(this);
     i=Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
     ch[k].setId(i);
     tr.addView(ch[k]);
     a[k++]=i;
     tr.addView(id);
     tr.addView(name1);
     tb.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
j++;
}
}

Comment: in above code i'm adding checkbox..n also assignin id to cehckbox..now see in delete function -

Comment: public void delete(View v){
  System.out.println("In delete");
  int bb=k,id = -1;
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  for(int bb2=0;bb<k;bb++)
  {
   for (int i=0; i <k; i++) {
   final int j = a[i];
                          ch[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
  System.out.println("Checked ID :: " + ch[j].getId());
      }
     });
 }
 dh.deleteData(id);
 Toast.makeText(this,"Deleted Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}

Comment: What is variable K here? Post your whole Activity code here, if possible.

Comment: k is integer..total no. of records r stored in dat

Comment: Datahelper is .java file.. where sqlite query is executed

Comment: Yes, I know that But I need That BDHelper class and also Layout XML

Comment: that files are large i couldn't copy here

Answer (score 2):

Views added dynamically do not have an ID until you specifically set them. So you need to call view.setId() on the view when you're adding to your layout, else you won't be able to reference it with view.getId().

I experienced a similar issue a while back when trying to dynamically create a RelativeLayout and positions the inner views relative to each other; they wouldn't align how they should have because the ID's didn't exist until I explicitly set one for them.

Also, why are you doing this:

```
ch.getId();
ch.setId(1);
```

That makes absolutely no sense. Take it out.

And also, you're going to need a reference linking the CheckBox to the View you want to delete. In this case, I would make a new ArrayList of Objects that have both a CheckBox and a View inside of it, IE.

```
public Class MyRow{        
    CheckBox c;
    View v;

    public MyRow() {   }        
}
```

Then when adding your views dynamically, add them to your MyRow or whatever class, then add that class to an ArrayList, and boom, you now have references between them and can remove the correct ones.

Comment: that getId n setid i was trying somthing else..at time of copying code that was also included

Comment: I would still take it out and make an ArrayList of an object that references both your View and the CheckBoc associated with it as they're being created.