# Android UI unit-tests: how to find dynamically added checkbox?

Tags: android, unit-testing, checkbox, android-espresso

In my android app, I have a `ListView` of custom items (made of a clickable title + one checkbox without text). Those items are dynamically added.

How can I check one of those checkboxes in my unit tests using Espresso or a similar framework ?

I can't find how to get a reference to one of the checkboxes. Since they are dynamically added, I can't find them by id, like I usually do with static .xml views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we did it without changing the app's code:

```
int indexOfItem = 1;
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView))
            .atPosition(indexOfItem)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.checkBox))
            .perform(click());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set id for the checkboxes programatically (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11349608/1219012) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898/1219012)).

```
    int checkBoxId = 200000; // global variable to count checkboxes
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
        box.setId(++checkBoxId);
    }
```

then find them as usual:

```
onView(withId(200003)).perform(click());
```

Comment: Won't the ids collide with the ids in my `.xml` ? For instance the one for a `EditText` ?

Comment: They can in theory. I looked into my app's R.java - all ids start with `0x7f` (`0x7f010176`). So your ids shouldn't collide if they are less then `0x7f000000`